# Shortcut/Link to another folder in TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, hyperlink, shortcut, share

We have a service written in one of our Team Projects.

It's in "Project A".  This service was modified to work not only for "Project A", but also for "Project B" which of course, is another Team Project.

Now, if a dev sees it running, it will be with a name that would make them look in Team Project B... but of course, the code isn't there, and they likely wouldn't know to go look for it in Team Project A.

Is there a way to add a shortcut or link to TFS from a folder in Team Project B to a location in Team Project A?

Comment: This was a couple of years ago. Does anyone know if TFS has updated this in recent history?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like if this were a feature but TFS doesn't support sharing like VSS did. http://blogs.msdn.com/buckh/archive/2004/06/10/152609.aspx

I think the suggested solution is to branch the code and when changes are made alert the other team so they can merge the changes into their solution. That way one project's changes don't have to wait for the other project to say ok.

On the other hand if they're both referencing the same deploied dll or web service this wouldn't work very well. If that's the case the only thing I can think of is to put a note in the folder for one of the projects saying go look at the other one where it is.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.
It's not even a shared dll.  
Just one app, that now belongs in two places in our TFS structure.
*sigh* It's not a branch.
I just want a link to existing code...why oh why must M$ take features away!

...'suppose I'll have to resort to a txt file saying where the code they are looking for is.